# How to approach and model these data - choosing an appropriate model

Tags: r, modeling, model-selection, time-varying-covariate

I have `group` data where each observation within group is time continuous. (named `time` in the sample data provided bellow`)

Further, I have `price` value in given time, `appr` appreciation/depreciation value, `mean1`, which is `diff(log(mean_values_1)` and further `mean2` and `mean3` which are mean values (mean of `price`) over different time period.
Further, I have variables `distance_mean_1_2` and `distance_mean_2_3`, which are the `distances` between `mean1`and `mean2 and distance between`mean2`and`mean3`.

What I would like to find out is at what `level` is the dependent variable `appreciation`, possitive and highest. Or better at which levels is the dependent variable `appr` maximised.

Also helful would be to find at which `levels` is the dependent value `appr` converging to possitive values fastest.

How to approch this. I have long format data. Would I have to turn the data into wide format? So taht each group has one 1 entry per row?

What model (time series?) to use?

I'm using software `R`.

**EDIT**: I'm thinking to model each of the independent (`explanatory`) variable one by one, using survival analysis. Would that be good approach?

**EDIT 2**: Here is some explanation and hopefully answers the questions raised in answer provided.

`1) Why is "convergence" either useful or helpful to know?`

The first row in given group is the starting point of measurement. Where `appr` is always zero. Based on simple command "stop if appr is >100" the measurement process is stopped. The final value is therefore equal or greater than 100. It is desired that the process stops (reaches level 100)
as soon as possible. So possbily I misused the word "convergence" here but what I meant is that the `appr` value reaches the desired value of 100 (or greater) over `time` as soon as possible.

Based on this I would like to find the appropriate covariate `levels` that would either maximize the number of possitive values in the given group or reaches the desired `appr` value of 100 in shorter period of time. 
So I would like to know at which `levels` is the best chance of achiving this.

`2 ) Issue with variable selection, Which of the predictors are most useful and/or predictive of appr?`

It is possible that some of the covariates are not significant in explaning the process of `appr`. So I would like to find out which covariates are significant. Of course fewer covariates in explaning the maximization or "convergence" would be desired so that the model is parsimonious.

Here is example: `samp` is the sample data (`dput`) provided bellow.

```
samp <- transform(samp, flag=with(samp, ifelse(appr<0, TRUE, FALSE)))

samp$appr <- round(samp$appr, -1)
samp$distance12 <- as.factor(round(samp$distance_mean_1_2, 2))
samp$distance23 <- as.factor(round(samp$distance_mean_2_3, 2))
```

Model fitted:

```
fittedsurv <- survfit(Surv(time=samp$time, samp$flag)~samp$distance12)
```

Here is sample data `dput()`.

> structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), time = c(1L, 
>   2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
>   16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
>   4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
>   13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), 
>       price = c(1.131975, 1.12895, 1.13415, 1.148075, 1.13455, 
>       1.1477, 1.13155, 1.132425, 1.132075, 1.1337, 1.140325, 1.139275, 
>       1.135375, 1.1411, 1.139725, 1.136825, 1.138125, 1.13345, 
>       1.134025, 1.13605, 1.1198, 1.1196, 1.11835, 1.11765, 1.10785, 
>       1.04955, 1.05675, 1.059725, 1.086375, 1.06595, 1.0822, 1.0889, 
>       1.0833, 1.07315, 1.076325, 1.087975, 1.097175, 1.0922, 1.081475, 
>       1.07805, 1.065925, 1.06045, 1.056725, 1.06545, 1.0684, 1.07615, 
>       1.0807, 1.073775, 1.07355, 1.072425, 1.082375, 1.087875, 
>       1.08915, 1.0981, 1.112825), appr = c(0, 2.67948093361093, 
>       -3.8354714984791, -40.1759466933778, 7.02921863293823, -50.3398100548923, 
>       20.3040077769427, 16.4249288032318, 17.9758408232671, 10.7832759989417, 
>       -18.3281082147637, -13.736806302254, 3.39095012660988, -21.7115064411535, 
>       -15.7055430037954, -2.99078574098922, -8.69851729818822, 
>       11.8884820680219, 9.34723661294901, 0.418115399850166, 72.981782461154, 
>       73.8879957127547, 79.5591719944562, 82.7405717353372, 127.702306268899, 
>       0, 6.81334279630953, 12.4088796621765, 85.6978483488664, 
>       35.695858154697, 110.238403252633, 0, -5.16938982737935, 
>       -24.134557144854, -15.2138062388219, 27.7809692318295, 80.0920545947553, 
>       57.681743270464, 8.66871633648522, -7.18890589490256, -64.1461641297459, 
>       -90.2918572304211, -108.235349783529, -66.4038669106945, 
>       -52.4148259078991, -16.029363936254, 5.08929397612705, -27.1239319224231, 
>       -28.1775418005677, -33.4522227661605, 12.8190322208116, 38.0328622314146, 
>       43.8415277969066, 84.2364083416819, 149.282232156898), mean1 = c(0, 
>       -0.000125909452303286, 0.000480767625671563, 0.00174112688697965, 
>       0.000197216307187068, 0.00121615479085431, -0.000174056350265378, 
>       -8.79262923791369e-05, -9.74266755982556e-05, 1.11326494046937e-05, 
>       0.000374958733439235, 0.000276277046605489, 5.45242034129256e-05, 
>       0.000314368832739276, 0.00022227302140948, 7.9401611874419e-05, 
>       0.000124234137939244, -6.56366814974774e-05, -3.90626893718993e-05, 
>       3.54238189215206e-05, -0.000518055394024303, -0.000486452734504011, 
>       -0.000491306161860133, -0.00809928321939048, -0.00388792727271271, 
>       -0.0475850358518138, -0.00148495851609912, -0.000766072854589614, 
>       0.00218079377247371, -0.000170151521123416, 0.00124375135307889, 
>       0.020066061096198, -0.000953967459985092, -0.00188206997886047, 
>       -0.00283135384960903, 0.000273465517020816, 0.00247455080838277, 
>       0.000367782277040249, -0.000447368358715838, -0.000608727159220307, 
>       -0.00226018102656933, -0.00121764245969647, -0.00127198932686792, 
>       -0.0125519550862929, -0.00204247878661268, -0.00029715125999033, 
>       0.00203360767447708, 0.000712653091219526, 0.00137546738904835, 
>       0.000213035364990496, 0.000951874176837356, 0.00119929844733625, 
>       0.0065522202860582, 0.00191263631850579, 0.00818748986560495
>       ), mean2 = c(0, -0.00704195826131931, -0.00627500719528225, 
>       -0.00498670169640732, -0.0017388799915012, -0.000170151521123416, 
>       0.00124375135307889, 0.0019985812499813, 0.00153382827948782, 
>       0.0016153716745991, 0.0008664183062876, 0.000786538278354385, 
>       0.00957930055086824, -0.00135328922328085, 0.00106180888463094, 
>       0.000158790614197574, 0.000899337518020904, 0.000367782277040249, 
>       -0.000447368358715838, -0.000608727159220307, -0.00127240852760666, 
>       -0.00143039032774157, -0.00146627716701067, -0.000856747310940417, 
>       -0.000623484107310557, -0.0075061543615107, 0.00111165484916645, 
>       0.00187789269737494, 0.00584401222055937, 0.00765319531854193, 
>       0.00466933643850007, 0.0210108262695513, -0.000278402833809296, 
>       0.000241605996257777, 0.00125095354341931, 0.00318688670096776, 
>       0.00147784903483378, 0.00039605384433157, -0.000632727654295839, 
>       -0.000866696154246824, -0.000668468141698117, -0.00108958570139681, 
>       -0.00113790320780324, -0.00238803637527786, -0.00112351686458498, 
>       -0.0112841232271361, -0.00329564306271869, -0.00225120329744991, 
>       0.00153773392023647, 0.00227537488894973, 0.00161864874852717, 
>       0.00117748472348102, 0.00142481132443494, 0.00119852645921323, 
>       0.00127765117220648), mean3 = c(0, -0.00149598876645349, 
>       -0.00441931783382968, -0.0076488409828849, -0.00113846821320018, 
>       -0.00163004372170902, -0.00225524378260492, -0.000608260910848812, 
>       -0.0023984593618408, -0.00121508194174377, -0.000987657107139134, 
>       -0.00478254128195757, -0.00753865101960935, -0.00587250593537236, 
>       -0.00213942676875745, -0.0063543836257087, -0.00136629361348317, 
>       0.000197312324906024, -0.000909369742590177, -0.000377384448124907, 
>       -0.00682093942827186, -0.00582763856655152, -0.00522235547636016, 
>       -0.00112828300967641, 0.000362339162043451, -0.0258114034483171, 
>       0.000480767625671563, 0.00174112688697965, 0.00581915353017895, 
>       0.00395788514502121, -0.00260335810375681, -0.00270979229966919, 
>       -0.000160469009492153, 0.000285748828725535, 0.000148759967614098, 
>       -5.45749504993476e-05, 2.88816280240856e-05, -0.000231586631810748, 
>       -0.000174642513644796, -5.63259988011489e-05, -0.00232587852123847, 
>       -0.00827312250145883, -0.00525754196268011, -0.000357446051793123, 
>       -0.00196824040279832, -0.00202446609436205, -0.0144237434071857, 
>       -0.00690479568146037, -0.0102274404029469, -0.00582252570132376, 
>       -0.0101565300751118, -0.00637225436126534, 0.0001992556525688, 
>       0.000682692009971946, 0.00572777812205827), distance_mean_1_2 = c(-0.0365579095629866, 
>       -0.0434739583720054, -0.0502297331929546, -0.0569575617763408, 
>       -0.058893658075035, -0.0602799643870113, -0.0588621566836718, 
>       -0.0567756491413051, -0.0551443941862192, -0.05354015516103, 
>       -0.0530486955881793, -0.0525384343564295, -0.043013658008976, 
>       -0.0446813160649942, -0.0438417802017707, -0.0437623911994467, 
>       -0.0429872878193627, -0.0425538688608303, -0.0429621745301677, 
>       -0.043606325508318, -0.0443606786418921, -0.0453046162351342, 
>       -0.0462795872402859, -0.0390370513318403, -0.0357726081664306, 
>       0.00430627332387412, 0.00690288668913117, 0.00954685224110112, 
>       0.0132100706891893, 0.0210334175288501, 0.0244590026142726, 
>       0.0254037677876287, 0.0260793324138063, 0.028203008388918, 
>       0.0322853157819468, 0.0351987369658929, 0.0342020351923428, 
>       0.0342303067596357, 0.0340449474640598, 0.0337869784690358, 
>       0.0353786913539018, 0.0355067481122096, 0.0356408342312711, 
>       0.0458047529422805, 0.0467237148643095, 0.0357367428971703, 
>       0.0304074921599643, 0.027443635771299, 0.0276059023024871, 
>       0.0296682418264462, 0.0303350163981333, 0.0303132026742835, 
>       0.0251857937126607, 0.0244716838533682, 0.017561845159964
>       ), distance_mean_2_3 = c(-0.09726297804778, -0.0958928987336336, 
>       -0.0909928132741315, -0.0816028454042668, -0.0802671608838797, 
>       -0.0774209623713145, -0.0753397749389736, -0.0748194403205009, 
>       -0.0725184076342605, -0.0712921930431132, -0.0699295772025403, 
>       -0.0648707588739723, -0.0572775836509485, -0.0510907088828391, 
>       -0.0487290090926736, -0.0422952238550939, -0.0408046961036684, 
>       -0.0410676451100696, -0.0401973380568562, -0.0397845297898041, 
>       -0.0334816457555634, -0.0281404599235143, -0.0234094106090121, 
>       -0.0303804108187229, -0.0346306772534791, -0.0564043096569832, 
>       -0.0583700357987467, -0.0608772355403157, -0.064515595298027, 
>       -0.0686436319641656, -0.0647965225073362, -0.0420206691114687, 
>       -0.0428141675619625, -0.0449819863695446, -0.0479621001867693, 
>       -0.0476340597192499, -0.0451883905388889, -0.0445890216300379, 
>       -0.0448617474751081, -0.0454141486355312, -0.0453484511408505, 
>       -0.0382929710990994, -0.0343074184632867, -0.0465019274977842, 
>       -0.0465761658815954, -0.0448488510472269, -0.0283914999655629, 
>       -0.0207740511928841, -0.00917114340088911, -0.00313558233457029, 
>       0.00797282191737423, 0.0155443747259729, 0.0218973393594655, 
>       0.0231272836679962, 0.0255869954115449)), .Names = c("group", 
>   "time", "price", "appr", "mean1", "mean2", "mean3", "distance_mean_1_2", 
>   "distance_mean_2_3"), row.names = c(NA, 55L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some aspects of your question aren't clear. While I think your first concern about the "levels" at which *appr* is "positive and highest" is clear and addressable, I don't know what is meant by your second question, "at which values *appr* converging to possitive (sic) values fastest." Perhaps more importantly, why is "convergence" either useful or helpful to know?

You are lucky in that your data isn't large. I wouldn't make this analysis too complicated. There is no reason why a classic ANOVA wouldn't deliver a reasonable answer to your question, in other words, I don't see how survival analysis can help you. Flattening, pushing down the stack or "widening" your file to create a single record would be variance-destroying and not a good idea. You do have an issue with variable selection -- which of the predictors are most useful and/or predictive of *appr*? I can't imagine that you would need all of them to fit a model, unless there is some *theoretical* reason that needs to be articulated.

Wrt your first concern about the "levels" which maximize *appr*, assuming that you are referring to the 3 possible groups, treating *group* as a qualitative predictor in an ANOVA and, perhaps, dropping the intercept you could obtain coefficients that would be your best indicator of the *level* where *appr* is maximized. It would also be worth your while to explore a few of the possible interactions, e.g., price by group, to obtain more representative estimates of the effects.

EDIT 2 Thoughts ************

I see what you mean by *convergence* now. This is a question that applies to the *sequencing* of the process. In examining time series line plots containing *appr* and *price* for the 3 groups, three things stand out suggesting very different processes at work for each group: first, price for group 2 is much higher than for the other 2 groups, second, price is positively related to appr for groups 2 and 3 and negatively related for group 1 and, finally, I'm left wondering why there is any nonlinear variability in price at all given how it's linearly related to appr in group 2 vs the others. In other words, as the sequence for a process unfolds, why doesn't price change as a linear function for each group instead of only for group 2? That would seem to suggest an immediate solution to the longer sequences for groups 1 and 3 as well as an answer to your question about *convergence* since the maximal value for *appr* would be reached with fewer steps.

In terms of variable selection, there are many approaches to that (everybody has an opinion about which approach is best). I rely on the Lasso. You can use one of the widely available R modules for this. On the other hand, the sheer number of possible covariates and their interactions are so few that you can almost do this step by hand and in the absence of some *automatic* routine. In fact, a careful specification of the predictors and their combinations might lead to better results.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this. I have now included answers to the questions you raised under `EDIT 2`. I would be grateful if you could extend your answer by reflecting on this new information. Thank you!